# FTS3 use of "BETWEEN"

Tags: android, fts3

I'm getting error in this code.

```
Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE KEY_ID BETWEEN 15 AND 20",
     null);
```

My LogCat says `error near ? ****** BETWEEN ?`
It says what are you doing. I'm not being able to figure out the mistake. Please help.

Comment: Is your column literally named `"KEY_ID"` or did you mean `"SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " BETWEEN 15 AND 20"`?

Comment: KEY_ID is my db table's column name which has a unique ID for every row.

Comment: but the point is.. LogCat is showing error near ?

Comment: Look closely at the syntax in my comment. See the difference? If this didn't help post your table schema.

Comment: Can you please answer me one more question..

Comment: Actually I want to retrieve the data for a specified range of dates. So, I'm storing it as an int so that I can use this BETWEEN tag. So I want to ask is it better to create two columns to store the dates as an int as well as a string.. so that I can use 1 to display & other one for easy data extraction or is it better to create just 1 column & store date as an int & then apply required changes to display it in my dynamic view. Therefore, my doubt is which one is faster.

Comment: In one option I'm making an extra column for table that will lead to extra burden at search time & in other option I'm adding extra burden to dynamic views which itself is very costly.

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I don't know if one approach is definitively faster than the other, unless you have a very large database it shouldn't matter too much. Using `BETWEEN` is easy to write and understand, so until your queries start slowing your app down, I recommend using `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `KEY_ID` is your variable, like `DATABASE_TABLE`, not the actual column name. Try:

```
Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " BETWEEN 15 AND 20",
     null);
```